# Problems push of view, UITabBarController and UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITabBarController and UINavigationController.
the code it is AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    _tabBarAppDelegate = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    LoginVC *loginViewController = [[LoginVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
    [_tabBarAppDelegate setViewControllers:@[loginViewController]];
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [self.window setRootViewController: _tabBarAppDelegate];
    // [self hideTabBar:self.tabBarAppDelegate];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES; 
}
```

In class have a login button with the code:

```
- (IBAction)buttonLogin:(id)sender
{
    DashVC * dashBoard = [[DashVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"DashVC" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dashBoard animated:YES];
}
```

I click on the button you can not do push the view DashVC.
Would anyone can explain what I'm doing wrong?
I debug and do not enter the method:

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
```

the class dashVC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code like this :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    _tabBarAppDelegate = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    LoginVC *loginViewController = [[LoginVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginViewController];
    [_tabBarAppDelegate setViewControllers:@[navigationController]];
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [self.window setRootViewController: _tabBarAppDelegate];
    // [self hideTabBar:self.tabBarAppDelegate];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

You need to add a `UINavigationController` inside your `LoginViewController`

Comment: what did you say ? I don't understand sorry. Did you try my code ?

Answer (score 1):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```